# Insert Data Frame to DB2 using RJDBC in R

Tags: r, dataframe, db2, rjdbc

How to insert data Frame into DB2 from R using RJDBC package.

I have tried multiple way most them failed.
Current method:
Converted the df into query using `paste`. 
then using `dbExecute(conn,req[1])` get the below error

```
 ([jcc][10103][10941][4.15.134] Method executeQuery cannot be used for update. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null)
```

Is there was to fix this error or need a sample code to insert dataframe into DB2

Sample Code:

```
library(JODBC)
jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver",
       "C:/Program/Files/IBM/db2jcc4.jar")

#Connection String         
conn = dbConnect(jcc,"jdbc:db2://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxxx/TESTDB","TESTUsser","XXXXXXX")


req <- paste("INSERT INTO TESTDB1.test (Inc_Number,Group,Resolved_TIME,Submit_Date,PROCESS_DATE) VALUES ('",df$Inc_Number,"','",df$Group,"','",df$Resolved_TIME,"','",df$Submit_Date,"',DEFAULT)",sep="")

lapply(req, function(x) dbExecute(conn, x))
```

`PROCESS_DATE` is sys.date

Sample data:

```
INCNO1  Group1  4/10/2017 13:48 4/10/2017 13:48
INCNO2  Group1  4/10/2017 13:43 4/10/2017 13:30
INCNO3  Group2  4/10/2017 14:26 4/10/2017 14:26
INCNO4  Group2  4/10/2017 13:31 4/10/2017 13:31
INCNO5  Group2  4/10/2017 13:33 4/10/2017 13:33
INCNO6  Group3  4/10/2017 13:11 4/10/2017 13:11
```

Getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Can you provide full code (not snippets) and data sample so we can reproduce?

Comment: @Parfait updated the question with sample data and code. If i run the SQL directly in DB2 it works. When I'm trying to insert through R its giving me error

Comment: Try `dbSendUpdate` or `dbSendQuery` per the [docs](http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/)

Comment: @Parfait Still getting the same error